# How to set up a gitlab project with wordpress and push local changes to live site

Tags: wordpress, git, gitlab

I am currently making changes to a WordPress site that another team has developed. I have been given access to the live WordPress site and using the Duplicator plugin to download a duplicate of the site for local development. I am using XAMMP to run the files locally with a copy of the DB.

I want to create a GitLab repo for this project so my team and I can make changes locally and push these changes to the live site. I want to have a main, stage, and various branches to track the different changes and only the main branch would push to the live site.

I am having difficulty understanding how to get this up and running since I am new to using WordPress, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There are several tutorials around the 'net about using git and WordPress. Many of them mention Github, and Gitlab will usually work for those too. And, a lot of folks use compose (php's module manager) to deploy WordPress. It will help you to read about those things to help plan your effort.